# Can I send a user-entered phone number to a server on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I know that Apple does not permit developers to read the phone number of the device and send that to a server.

However, I can't find anything about whether I can send the phone number of the current device **if the user enters it into the app**.

I would like to let people sign up to my service using only their phone number as an identifier (i.e. no need for an email address) and to send them an SMS with a secret code to authenticate them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can do that. The reason you can't read the phone number is that it requires a private API call.

An even more user-friendly method could be to allow the user to select their phone number from the address book.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that would indeed be better. Can you select the phone's own number from the address book or would I need to have myself set up as a contact?

Comment: The user has to have set themselves up as a contact. This might not be the case so you'd have to allow them to enter it directly if not.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks again - very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Viber does. You are permitted to send any user data to your server - as long as the user knows exactly what data is that and allows you to do it.